# OAuth2Client clientId and clientSecret not set

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I've set up a working IdentityServer 3 and everything works fine except the refresh token I'm trying to add.

I avoid to report the whole code because I think I spot the error

```
var tokenClient = new OAuth2Client(new Uri("https://myServer/myIdentityServer/connect/token"), "clientId", "secretWord");
var response = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(n.Code, n.RedirectUri);
```

I get an error in the second line, and debugging I found that `tokenClient` variable contains a few private properties that are set to `null` but shouldn't be

> _address: {https://myServer/myIdentityServer/connect/token}
>
> _authenticationStyle: None
>
> _client: {System.Net.Http.HttpClient}
>
> _clientId: null
>
> _clientSecret: null

Why `_clientId` and `_clientSecret` are set to `null`? I gave the 2 parameters directly to `OAuth2Client` constructor, am I doing something wrong here?

---

UPDATE: following Scott Brady suggestion I tried also with `TokenClient` class from `IdentityModel`. Nothing changed, the `response` variable report an HttpError "Internal Server Error".

From IdentityServer side everything seems to be fine, the log from first part of request is good

```
2015-11-10 14:31:36.737 +01:00 [Information] Start authorize request
2015-11-10 14:31:36.737 +01:00 [Information] Start authorize request protocol validation
2015-11-10 14:31:36.738 +01:00 [Information] "Authorize request validation success"
 "{
  \"ClientId\": \"hybridclient\",
  \"ClientName\": \"Hybrid Client Example\",
  \"RedirectUri\": \"https://rbmidde02.xxx.com/miIdentityClient/\",
  \"AllowedRedirectUris\": [
    \"https://rbmidde02.xxx.com/miIdentityClient/\"
  ],
  \"SubjectId\": \"1\",
  \"ResponseType\": \"code id_token token\",
  \"ResponseMode\": \"form_post\",
  \"Flow\": \"Hybrid\",
  \"RequestedScopes\": \"openid profile email roles offline_access\",
  \"State\": \"OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=joIq4Na_pIjM1dGht8LPOhXbzPjnHnlFgOPll_oxPbAH9GIuFQ5SKHUZWgRFUih_OFGTWxmi8I_Fu7pS_t_V_R2cNDa7l6r0eQ4RfgTosHHhmdpfm-0YuAO-N5q_16WyqesLPckv6HrB7ruZ64m8Vu4mpA80RYjc46xalOdzkyrKQLlmt_AwlWGA6XY-B2P3WpVvcP_tZQywdMEFS9uF-ucK07UOeUwO6nV8QXGJ-g31WhmM4D1I83O3EaYnoB2Xf6bOAMJuMySTywwQQ-bdd-tiOoRsusqSuc-JeeOiZvY\",
  \"Nonce\": \"635827590967269474.ZmM0NjgwYzMtZTYwMC00MmI5LTk5YzUtZjdhMmQ4MTkyZTUwNDBjZTkwYzEtYTBlNy00MDM2LTk4ZjUtMWEzYmZjZmZmMTc2\",
  \"SessionId\": \"7eb1b6356ef9ecb843dde1afdb239d9e\",
  \"Raw\": {
    \"client_id\": \"hybridclient\",
    \"redirect_uri\": \"https://rbmidde02.xxx.com/miIdentityClient/\",
    \"response_mode\": \"form_post\",
    \"response_type\": \"code id_token token\",
    \"scope\": \"openid profile email roles offline_access\",
    \"state\": \"OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=joIq4Na_pIjM1dGht8LPOhXbzPjnHnlFgOPll_oxPbAH9GIuFQ5SKHUZWgRFUih_OFGTWxmi8I_Fu7pS_t_V_R2cNDa7l6r0eQ4RfgTosHHhmdpfm-0YuAO-N5q_16WyqesLPckv6HrB7ruZ64m8Vu4mpA80RYjc46xalOdzkyrKQLlmt_AwlWGA6XY-B2P3WpVvcP_tZQywdMEFS9uF-ucK07UOeUwO6nV8QXGJ-g31WhmM4D1I83O3EaYnoB2Xf6bOAMJuMySTywwQQ-bdd-tiOoRsusqSuc-JeeOiZvY\",
    \"nonce\": \"635827590967269474.ZmM0NjgwYzMtZTYwMC00MmI5LTk5YzUtZjdhMmQ4MTkyZTUwNDBjZTkwYzEtYTBlNy00MDM2LTk4ZjUtMWEzYmZjZmZmMTc2\"
  }
}"
2015-11-10 14:31:36.738 +01:00 [Information] Creating Hybrid Flow response.
2015-11-10 14:31:36.738 +01:00 [Information] Creating Implicit Flow response.
2015-11-10 14:31:36.749 +01:00 [Information] Getting claims for identity token for subject: 1
2015-11-10 14:31:36.757 +01:00 [Information] End authorize request
2015-11-10 14:31:36.757 +01:00 [Information] Posting to https://rbmidde02.xxx.com/miIdentityClient/
```

But also second part seems ok

```
2015-11-10 14:31:36.905 +01:00 [Information] Start userinfo request
2015-11-10 14:31:36.905 +01:00 [Information] Token found: AuthorizationHeader
2015-11-10 14:31:36.905 +01:00 [Information] Start access token validation
2015-11-10 14:31:36.906 +01:00 [Information] "Token validation success"
"{
  \"ValidateLifetime\": true,
  \"AccessTokenType\": \"Jwt\",
  \"ExpectedScope\": \"openid\",
  \"Claims\": {
    \"client_id\": \"hybridclient\",
    \"scope\": [
      \"openid\",
      \"profile\",
      \"email\",
      \"roles\",
      \"offline_access\"
    ],
    \"sub\": \"1\",
    \"amr\": \"password\",
    \"auth_time\": \"1447153048\",
    \"idp\": \"idsrv\",
    \"iss\": \"https://rbmidde02.xxx.com/miIdentityServer\",
    \"aud\": \"https://rbmidde02.xxx.com/miIdentityServer/resources\",
    \"exp\": \"1447165896\",
    \"nbf\": \"1447162296\"
  }
}"
2015-11-10 14:31:36.907 +01:00 [Information] Creating userinfo response
2015-11-10 14:31:36.907 +01:00 [Information] Scopes in access token: "openid profile email roles offline_access"
2015-11-10 14:31:36.907 +01:00 [Information] Requested claim types: "sub name family_name given_name middle_name nickname preferred_username profile picture website gender birthdate zoneinfo locale updated_at email email_verified role"
2015-11-10 14:31:36.907 +01:00 [Information] Profile service returned to the following claim types: "sub given_name family_name email role role preferred_username"
2015-11-10 14:31:36.907 +01:00 [Information] End userinfo request
2015-11-10 14:31:36.907 +01:00 [Information] Returning userinfo response.
```

Response is ok from IdentityServer side, I don't understand why that Internal Server Error on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't had much experience with the `OAuth2Client` class. However I do know the TokenClient class from [IdentityModel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel) works with Identity Server and uses almost identical code to the above.

I would recommend giving this a go, as it's made by the same team as Identity Server.

See [here](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel#tokenclient) for example usage and GitHub repository.

Comment: I tried with `TokenClient`, I just had to change  `Uri` argumento to `string`, but result is the same. By checking `response` variable I see and HttpError "Internal Server Error". I can't understand what's wrong, the token endpoint url seems correct, like the client id and the secret.

Comment: offtopic: I just realized I was using your blog examples, thay are clear and easy to follow, well done! ;)